# How do I search for an element from each node in C++ using queue?

Tags: c++

To be more specific, I am working on a function that detects the element that exists in a set of nodes that were entered from the user. For example, lets say the user enqueued items that contain name, date, ID... And that user enqueued over 5 items, I want to check for a specific ID each one by one and output "Found!!!"...

This is what I have come so far, but I keep on getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x40) on Xcode.. Same thing to Visual Studio as well..

```
void lookup(int _patient_id)
{
    node *newnode = new node;
    newnode = front;

    while (newnode->next != NULL)
    {
        if (newnode->patient_id == _patient_id)
            cout<<"Found!!!!!!!";
        else
            newnode = newnode->next;
    }

}
```

Comment: This is most certainly wrong and demonstrates lack of knowledge about basic principles of C++.

Comment: You appear to be allocating a new node and leaking it, for no reason whatsoever. And your search will skip the last node in the list. If the node actually is found you'll go into an infinite loop. It's impossible to tell what's causing the crash without seeing what else you've got wrong.

Comment: For starters, you de-rerefence `newnode` without checking whether it is `NULL`.

Comment: Why do you allocate `newnode`, when you immediately forget about it? Please post a copy-paste-able example that anyone can check if you cant pin point the error. You can crash when the list empty for example. No one knows it.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Everything worked fine (including Enqueue, Dequeue, and Print..) but except this function that was supposed to walk step-by-step for each node and fetch me that element... If you would like me to re-post all my implementation I can do that.

Comment: Because your question is strictly off-topic: [Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how your function probably should look, but if you still get crashes it means something else is wrong in your program and we would need to see more code.

```
node* lookup(int _patient_id)
{
    node *newnode = front;
    while (newnode != NULL)
    {
        if (newnode->patient_id == _patient_id)
        {
            cout<<"Found!!!!!!!";
            return newnode;
        }
        newnode = newnode->next;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: In real life a lookup/search function will always return what it finds rather than just printing out "Found!!!!!!!". You can change it back to `void` if you want, but make sure you leave the `return` statement in when the node is found, otherwise you'll go back to a crash or infinite loop.

Comment: I was just adding the "Found!!!" output just for testing purposes.. Not because I lack knowledge C++.. Anyway thanks!